# Returning GuzzleHttp response object causes ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING in browser

Tags: php, laravel, http, laravel-5, guzzle6

I'm using guzzle 6 in laravel 5 to send a post request but I'm getting ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING when I try to access the request() in the method that handles the post request.

Here's my code:

Routes.php

```
Route::get('/guzzle', [
    'as'   => 'guzzle-test',
    'uses' => 'TestController@getTest'
]);

Route::post('/guzzle', [
   'as'   => 'guzzle-post-test',
   'uses' => 'TestController@postTest'
]);
```

TestController.php

```
public function getTest()
{
    $client = new Client();

    $data = [
        'hey' => 'ho'
    ];

    $request = $client->post(route('guzzle-post-test'), [
        'content-type' => 'application/json'
    ], json_encode($data));

    return $request;
}

public function postTest()
{
    dd(getTest());
}
```

I getting to the post request handler since I've tried to diedump a string and it gets there, but if i call the `request()` I get that error. For what I've researched It may have something to with the content length, but after reading guzzle's docs and some stuff around the web I could find how to get and pass the content length appropriately in the request. Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, here's some test code which you should be able to adapt for your purposes (also see [`form_params`](https://guzzle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/request-options.html#form-params) in the docs for GuzzleHttp):

```
public function validateRecaptcha()
{
    $client = new Client;
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
            'form_params' => [
                'secret' => env('RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
                'response' => Request::input('g-recaptcha-response'),
                'remoteip' => Request::ip()
            ]
    ]);

    return $response;
}
```

I just ran into the same issue and found that trying to return the response object in Laravel gave me `ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING`. Whereas, doing a `dd()` on the response itself showed me what I was actually wanting to see:

```
public function validateRecaptcha()
{
    $client = new Client;
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
            'form_params' => [
                'secret' => env('RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
                'response' => Request::input('g-recaptcha-response'),
                'remoteip' => Request::ip()
            ]
    ]);

    dd($response);
}
```

Unfortunately, without doing further research, I'm unable to explain why `ERR_INVALID_CHUNKED_ENCODING` keeps coming up when I try to return the client library's objects to the browser, but my initial inclination is that it's a data type issue.

As far as your question goes, you're not actually trying to get back the "request" but rather the *response*. According to http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#using-responses, if you want to get the API response contained in the response object (or at least in my case, I did), you'll want to use the `getBody()` method:

```
public function validateRecaptcha()
{
    $client = new Client;
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
            'form_params' => [
                'secret' => env('RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
                'response' => Request::input('g-recaptcha-response'),
                'remoteip' => Request::ip()
            ]
    ]);

    return $response->getBody();
}
```

And then of course, if you expect it to be a JSON response (i.e. REST), then simply pass it to `json_decode()` to get your associative array back.

```
public function validateRecaptcha()
{
    $client = new Client;
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', [
            'form_params' => [
                'secret' => env('RECAPTCHA_SECRET'),
                'response' => Request::input('g-recaptcha-response'),
                'remoteip' => Request::ip()
            ]
    ]);

    return json_decode($response->getBody(), true); // true = assoc. array
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very helpful!